# How Can I prevent Duplicates in my database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a CSV File that I am throwing into a DB. It does this correctly but I dont want repeating records obviously. Any Ideas how I can record only unique ones? I don't want to throw them into the DB then run a `DELETE` query because well thats not time effective.

```
if (($handle = fopen($csvfile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
                $count ++;
                if ($count > 1) {
                    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO $table2 (id, cat) VALUES ('".$data[0]."', '".$data[1]."')");  
                    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO $table1 (id, cat) VALUES ('".$data[2]."', '".$data[3]."')"); 
                    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO $table3 (id, word) VALUES ('".$data[4]."', '".$data[5]."')"); 
                    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO $table4 (id, cl, co, imp) VALUES ('".$data[0]."','".$data[6]."', '".$data[7]."', '".$data[8]."')"); 
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: make unique columns? use something like PDO to skip duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is after inserting all the records you can add a unique index and drop the duplicates with

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table
ADD UNIQUE INDEX dup_idx (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_3);
```

Another way is that add this unique index before insertion then use `insert ignore` query

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (column1,column2) VALUES ('value1','value2');
```

This will ignore the error occuring on insertion of duplicate entries since unique index is there also it will skip the duplicate entry insertion.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use teh unique key way or you can use

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS
```

on a specific column which you are considering to find the duplicate.
So it will be like

```
Insert into table name() values () where not exists (Select statement)
```